# Spring security and oauth2 Okta facing the invalid credential after logged in

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, openid, okta

I am trying to implement spring security on my reactive project with oauth2 from okta. And use openid too. But after logging in I get invalid credentials.
[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19Hwg.png)

In the Okta log, I successfully logged in
[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxRlq.png)

I have also assigned users to my application on the Okta portal
[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27D2V.png)

my properties:

```
okta:
  oauth2:
    issuer: https://dev-71346557.okta.com/oauth2/default
    audience: api://default
    client-id: <My Client Id>
    client-secret: <My Client Secret>
    scopes: openid, email, profile, offline_access
```

my spring config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class OktaOAuth2WebSecurity {

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http
                .authorizeExchange()
                .anyExchange().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt();
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

I have checked several explanations and documentation related to this, but the results are still the same.

I hope that after logging in it will display a json response in the form of a token and data of the logged in user

Comment: Make sure your client ID and secret match what you have in your Okta dashboard. That's the only thing I can think of.

Comment: The logs with `logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG` would be more useful than UI screen-shot, but Matt Raible is most probably right: double check client ID and secret. If it keeps failing after you are sure those two are correctly configured, add your logs to your question. As a side note, I strongly advise you to put `oauth2Login` and `oauth2ResourceServer` configurations in different `SecurityFilterChain` beans, it is too different (or remove the one you're not using).